# SQL to show concurrent cases

Tags: sql

Need help with SQL to show concurrency by person for every minute in a day.
for a data set below:

```
drop table test

create table test (person varchar(2), caseid varchar(3), starttime datetime, endtime datetime)
insert into test values ('aa', '1', '01/01/2013 06:42', '01/01/2013 07:06')
insert into test values ('aa', '1', '01/01/2013 07:31', '01/01/2013 09:38')
insert into test values ('aa', '2', '01/01/2013 08:37', '01/01/2013 11:44')
insert into test values ('aa', '3','01/01/2013 09:39', '01/01/2013 11:31')
insert into test values ('aa', '4','01/01/2013 11:09', '01/01/2013 13:30')
insert into test values ('aa', '5','01/01/2013 12:05', '01/01/2013 15:38')
insert into test values ('aa', '6', '01/01/2013 13:58', '01/01/2013 14:13')
insert into test values ('aa', '7', '01/01/2013 15:53', '01/01/2013 16:14')
insert into test values ('bb', '8', '01/01/2013 08:42', '01/01/2013 09:06')
insert into test values ('bb', '8', '01/01/2013 10:31', '01/01/2013 19:38')
insert into test values ('bb', '8','01/01/2013  20:37', '01/01/2013 21:44')
insert into test values ('bb', '9', '01/01/2013 09:39', '01/01/2013 11:31')
insert into test values ('bb', '9', '01/01/2013 11:45', '01/01/2013 13:30')
insert into test values ('bb', '9', '01/01/2013 12:05', '01/01/2013 15:38')
insert into test values ('bb', '10', '01/01/2013 13:58', '01/01/2013 14:13')
insert into test values ('bb', '10', '01/01/2013 15:53', '01/01/2013 16:14')
```

the result needs to be similar to the following:

```
aa  01/01/2013 6:42     1
aa  01/01/2013 6:43     1
aa  01/01/2013 6:44     1
....
....
aa  01/01/2013 8:37     2
aa  01/01/2013 8:38     2
....
....
bb  01/01/2013 8:42     1
bb  01/01/2013 8:43     1
bb  01/01/2013 10:31    2
....
....
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what the results show. What is 6:43 for example for person aa? Do you need a minute-by-minute listing showing how many discrete cases are extant for that person, in that minute, so that for each person you would have 60 rows per hour x 24? Or does the span go minute-by-minute from the earliest start time to the latest end-time, per person?

Comment: Are you using a particular DBMS? Which one? What version? It's a tad hard to answer when we don't know which database system you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
Select t.*,
           (Select count(*) 
            From t t2
            Where t2. Start <= t.start and
                        T2.end >= t.end
           )  numoverlaps
From t
```

(Apologies for syntax errors; I'm on a mobile device)

This finds concurrency at every time in the input data.  It does not do it for every minute of time.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as asked. Not in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

```
This seems to work, but there may be a more elegant solution:

-- get range of days involved
declare @minDate date = (select MIN(starttime) from test)
declare @maxDate date = (select MAX(endtime) from test)

-- create table containing all days
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#days') is not null
    drop table #days

create table #days (d date)
declare @day date = @minDate
while @day <= @maxDate
begin
    insert #days (d) values (@day)
    set @day = DATEADD(day, 1, @day)
end

-- create table containing all minutes in the day
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#minutes') is not null
    drop table #minutes

create table #minutes (m int)

declare @minute int = 0
while @minute < 24*60
begin
    insert #minutes (m) values (@minute)
    set @minute = @minute + 1
end

select person, dateadd(minute, m, convert(datetime, startdate)), c from
(
    select person, m, startdate, count(m) c from 
    (
        -- cross join to select all days and minutes
        select d.d, m.m from #days d cross join #minutes m
    )
    t0
    inner join
    (
        select 
            person, 
            convert(date, starttime) startdate,
            datediff(minute, convert(date, starttime), starttime) startmin,
            datediff(minute, convert(date, endtime), endtime) endmin
        from test
    )
    t1
    on t0.m between t1.startmin and t1.endmin
    and t0.d = t1.startdate
    group by person, m, startdate
)
t2
order by person, startdate, m, c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach it if using a database that supports CTE and inline views:

1. First a CTE to generate a two-col listing of the (24*60) minutes of the day for a specified date:

   time1             time2

   2013-02-12 00:00,  2013-02-12 00:01
      .
      .
      .
      2013-02-12 23:59,  2013-02-13 00:00
2. Left join that CTE to your cases table where cases.starttime between time1 and time2 or cases.endtime between time1 and time2. That brings back either nulls where no part of the case was ongoing during that minute or the caseid and personid when a case *was* ongoing during that minute.
3. Make the above an inline view.   You end up with a set of all minutes in the day and the left-joined caseid and personid, or nulls:

   time1, time2,  caseid, personid
4. If you select  from that inline view `where caseid is not null` you end up with the minutes where one or more cases was ongoing; if you then `group by personid, time1` and count(caseid) you get the tally of cases per person in that particular one-minute time slot.